# Calling functions randomly using a vector

Tags: c++

```
#assume everything needed is included
void Robot::moveRobot()
{
//calls a random directon for robot to move in

//if direction returns false (not able to move in that direction),
//call another random direction up to 4 times, excluding the one(s) 
//already called. If they all return false, do not move the robot.

//vecDir = {moveForward(), moveBackward(), moveRight(), moveLeft()}
//       = {0,1,2,3} initially

    vector<int> vecDir{0,1,2,3};        //vetor indicating direction to move
    int num = rand() % vecDir.size();

    if(num == vecDir[0])        
    {
        //if not able to move forward, try a different random direction
        if(Robot::moveForward() == false)
        {
            vecDir.erase(num);
            //here, vector will be vecDir={1,2,3}
        }
    }

    else if(num == vecDir[1])
    {
        Robot::moveBackward(); 
    }

    else if(num == vecDir[2])
    {           
        Robot::moveRight();
    }

    else    //num == vecDir[3]
    {           
        Robot::moveLeft();      
    }

 }
```

Hi! I'm trying to randomly call these four functions within the moveRobot() function using a vector whose size is changed depending on if a direction cannot be called. I set moveForward() to the first element, moveBackward() to the second element, etc. If any of the moveXXXX() functions are false, I want to delete that element of the array. Example code shown

```
Example output:
//before doing anything, vecDir = {0,1,2,3}

int num = rand() % vecDir.size();      //assume num = 1, so it calls moveBackward()
//assume moveBackward() is false, so gets rid of that element

vecDir.erase(num);                     //new vecDir = {0,2,3}; 
// vecDir(0) would be moveForward(), vecDir(1) is now moveRight(), vecDir(1) is now moveLeft()
```

How would I continue this process to exhaust all elements and not move a robot? I know a for loop would be involved, but I cannot think of where to use it. I am also not sure if my thinking is correct by using `if else` for each element. Any help is appreciated, and I apologize if the question is confusing. I can clear it up if there are any misunderstandings.

Comment: In order to make a [mcve] (as is appreciated here) you don't need a robot. Do you need a loop that gives you `X` (where `X` is `4`) directions? `rand()` is bad, but `rand() % vecDir.size()` when `size()` is 4 is ... worse. Do `rand() & 3` (`0b11`) and you'll have 0-3.

Comment: Nudge: the direction you want to try moving is given by `vecDir[num]`.

Comment: Instead of a for loop to find a direction try a `while(vecDir.size()) {` and have each movement when false remove an item from the vector and when true it should `break;` out of the while loop.  Then the loop continues until either the robot moved or all four of the movement options have been false and the vector is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a vector of function pointers, rather then numbers.

```
void Robot::moveRobot() {
   // vector of pointers to functions to move
   std::vector<bool()> moves{
          moveForward(), moveBackward(), moveRight(), moveLeft()
   };
   // we repeat the process until any moves are available.
   while (moves.size() > 0) {
       // pick a random move
       const int num = rand() % moves.size();
       // try to move
       if (moves[num]() == true) {
           // yay, we moved!
           break;
       }
       // we did not move - remove current option and repeat
       moves.erase(moves.begin() + num);
   }
}
```